# Create list of computers to disable

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, scripting

I have been tasked with automating our disabling/deleting of old computers.  Unfortunately I found out the hard way that the data I am being given for this task has many errors and I am having issues validating it.  The requirements here are that the computer account must exist, it cannot be a duplicate, it cannot be a server OS and the account password for the computer must not have been reset in the last 10 days.  I have been able to validate all of this seperately but when I attempt to combine the validation into one script I am failing.  Specifically I am unable to get past the duplicate data step. 
Here is the code:

```
$file = "D:\Transcripts\ADPCverify\" + (get-date -Format yyyymmdd-hhmmss) + ".txt"
start-transcript -LiteralPath $file 
$date = Get-Date
$computers = Get-Content D:\Content\ADPCverify\unverified.txt | sort-object -unique
$list =   Get-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\computers.txt 
$name = 'null'
ForEach($computer in $computers){
    $prevname = $name
    $name = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer -Server server).name
    $PCObject = Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer -Server server -Properties *
    $OS = $PCObject.OperatingSystem
                $pwdLastSet = [DateTime]::FromFiletime([Int64]::Parse($PCobject.pwdLastSet))
                $TimeSince = New-TimeSpan $pwdLastSet $date
    if($name -eq $prevname){
        Add-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\FailedComputers.txt $computer
        write-host "Machine " + $computer + " does not exist and has been added to the failed computers list."
    }elseif($OS -contains 'Windows Server'){
         Add-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\FailedComputers.txt $computer
         write-host "Machine " + $computer + " has a server OS and will be added to the failed computer list."
    }elseif($TimeSince.totaldays -lt 10){
         Add-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\FailedComputers.txt $computer
         write-host "Machine " + $computer + "'s password was reset " + $TimeSince.totaldays + "  days ago and has been added to the failed computer list."
    }else{
         Add-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\Computers.txt $name
         write-host "Machine " + $name + " has been succesfully added to the computers to disable list."
    }
} 
Stop-Transcript
```

The script seems to be unable to go past the second if statement.  Please let me know if I need to provide any more information or I am missing a bracket.

Comment: It would be good if you could give an example of the invalid data.  So do you have duplicate names in the `D:\Content\ADPCDisable\computers.txt ` file?    Do you actually need to throw an error in that case, or is simply de-duplicating that file enough?  (Dedup with something like `$list = Get-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\computers.txt | sort-object -unique`)

Comment: BTW, there is a `ElseIf` statement that you can use that would make your code less ugly. So `If (cond) {} ElseIf (cond) {} ElseIf (cond) {} ElseIf (cond) {} Else {}`.

Comment: For the the duplicate data I do not need to throw the error .  Also, I update my script with else if.  Originally I had split all of these out and was adding each invalid piece to a separate list and I had just copied and pasted the If statements from the separate scripts. This is necessary because the area where the data is coming from insists they have verified the data.  Examples of bad data: any server OS and any machine that has been active in the past 3 days.  Script updated above.

Comment: I see you updated things but did the sort-object -unique remove the duplicate data you said you were having problems with?

Comment: I just finished testing and it did remove the duplicates.  It is still getting stuck at the checking for server OS section.

Comment: Updated again to fix the $time since error check.  In case its not clear to anyone reading this that check will see if the comptuer has reset its password in the last 10 days.  this matters because computers are not supposed to hit this list unless they have been inactive for 30days.

Comment: OK, your problem with the OS check is that the `-contains` doesn't work they way you think it does.  Contains looks for an  exact match within a list.  In your cases you have a single element list.  What you probably want is the `-like` operator.  So `$OS -like '*Windows Server*'`.

Comment: It would be much easier to filter against this in your Get-ADComputer search. -Filter {OperatingSystem -notlike "\*Server\*"} It would be much simpler for you to discard the data source you've been given and find your own based on the known criteria. But using this filter would still exclude servers and would work in your context.

Comment: Unfortunately the data I am provided is a requirement for this task.  You guys both gave me a great start.  The -filter option worked but I wanted to make sure I had a list of failed machines and the -like option didn't catch the server OS for some reason.  I was able to use .startswith to get it done.  Thanks for the responses guys.  I really enjoy learning from other users on this site.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = "D:\Transcripts\ADPCverify\" + (get-date -Format yyyymmdd-hhmmss) + ".txt"
start-transcript -LiteralPath $file 
$date = Get-Date
$computers = Get-Content D:\Content\ADPCverify\unverified.txt | sort-object -unique
$list =   Get-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\computers.txt 
$name = 'null'
$server = ''
ForEach($computer in $computers){
    Try{
        $PCObject = Get-ADComputer -Identity $computer -Server $server -Properties *
        $name = $PCObject.Name
        $OS = $PCObject.OperatingSystem
        $pwdLastSet = [DateTime]::FromFiletime([Int64]::Parse($PCobject.pwdLastSet)) 
        $TimeSince = New-TimeSpan $pwdLastSet $date
        if($OS.StartsWith('Windows Server')){
            Add-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\FailedComputers.txt $computer
            write-host "Machine "  $computer  " has a server OS and will be added to the failed computer list."
        }elseif($TimeSince.TotalDays -lt 10){
            Add-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\FailedComputers.txt $computer
            write-host "Machine "  $computer  "'s password was reset " + $TimeSince.TotalDays + "  days ago and has been added to the failed computer list."
        }else{
            Add-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\Computers.txt $name
            write-host "Machine "  $name  " has been succesfully added to the computers to disable list."
        }
        }
     Catch{
        Add-Content D:\Content\ADPCDisable\FailedComputers.txt $computer
        write-host "Machine "  $computer  " does not exist and has been added to the failed computers list."
     }

} 
Stop-Transcript
```

This is the final result.  I used the try/catch option to suppress errors. My issue was with the -contains comparison.  Thanks for all the help!